# Pass Selected Radio Value to PHP using onclick, then opening php file to use value in SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, radio-button

I am pretty new to coding php and javascript but have manged to scrape my way through so far.  However, I have hit a wall.  I'm not 100% sure that what I'm trying to do can be done, or that I'm even attempting it in an effective way.

I have a dynamically filled table, made of rows from a SQL statement using php.  On each row is a radio button, each one given a unique value based on the row number (a unique value in one of the database columns).  I am attempting to program a button that enables the user to pass a selected radio button value to a separate php enabled page that will allow the user to edit the row information using the unique row value.  Also, i used the confirm option, because I would also like to add an if else statement that allows the user to cancel, if the wrong row was selected (I haven't attempted that yet because I haven't been able to get the value to pass).

Page button

`<input type="button" id="edit_order_button" value="Edit Order"></input>`

JQuery page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#edit_order_button").click(function(){
  var selected = $("input[name ='order_edit_select']:checked").val();
  var r = confirm("Confirm Order Number to edit: " + selected);
  $.post("php/editOrder.php", {
  selected1: selected
  }, function(data,status) {
  //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  window.open("php/editOrder.php","Edit Order","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=750,height=600, left=250, top=50");
});
});
});
```

PHP end destination

```html
<?php
//Login to database (usually this is stored in a separate php file and included in each file where required)
require('config.php');
$selected2= isset($_POST['selected1']) ? $_POST['selected1'] : ''; // Fetching Values from URL

echo "Selected Row number is ".$selected2.".";

mysqli_close($connection); // Connection Closed.
?>
```

I have tried a few things but have so far been unsuccessful in getting the new window to load with the value of the radio button passed.  Currently, the window loads, but the new window only displays the echo text, no variable.  When I run with the alert popup, the data shows me the value of the selected row but it does not seem to be posting to the new page prior to the window.open command.  Any tips would be appreciated, or if i'm approaching the problem from a wrong angle, any insights would also be great.  I have also tried debugging, thinking I was missing a parentheses or semicolon but I wasn't able to find anything.  Thanks

Comment: Do you want to `post` and then open the same PHP script in a new window? Looks to me like you can get rid of the `post` altogether and just pass the selection to the newly opened window. Am I missing something?

Comment: The value will be set when you do the AJAX call, but you're not displaying that result. When you use `window.open()`, you're not posting the form, so `$_POST['selected1']` won't be set, and it will display an empty row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you can get rid of the `post` statement altogether and just pass the selection to the newly opened window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit_order_button").click(function(){
        var selected = $("input[name ='order_edit_select']:checked").val();
        // only open window if order okayed
        if ( confirm("Confirm Order Number to edit: " + selected) ) {
            window.open("php/editOrder.php?selected1=" + selected,"Edit Order","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=750,height=600, left=250, top=50");
        }
    });
});
```

*php/editOrder.php:*

```
$selected2 = $_GET['selected1'];
echo "Selected Row number is $selected2.";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I like the simplicity, I was unaware you could pass the value in the window.open function.  The confirm ok/cancel works perfect.  However, the window is opening about:blank. I'm not seeing any content on the popup.  I tested the editOrder php page navigating directly to it.  I was getting an undefined index error.  So I added the
    $selected2= isset($_GET['selected1']) ? $_GET['selected1'] : '';

Still did not fix.  Not seeing any echo statement on the new window.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Oops. I used a PHP `.` concatenation, rather than a JavaScript `+` concatenation. My response is fixed and tested working.